# Returns delegate function NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I am trying to test a delegate function using NSubstitute:

```
_myMock.CallDelegateIfKeyMissing(Arg.Any<string>, Arg.Any<Func<Task<string>>>())
.Returns(
   //The results of the delegate function "Arg.Any<Func<Task<string>>>"
);
```

Is this possible please? Thank you

Comment: `Task.FromResult("some string")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Func<Task<string>>` argument from within the `Returns` and invoke it:

```
_myMock
    .CallDelegateIfKeyMissing(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<Func<Task<string>>>())
    .Returns(
        x => x.Arg<Func<Task<string>>>().Invoke()
    );

var result = _myMock.CallDelegateIfKeyMissing("hi", () => Task.FromResult("world"));

Assert.Equal("world", result.Result);
```

There's a bit more information in the [NSubstitute documentation](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/).

Comment: Thank you! I am guessing if the x.Arg<Func<Task<string>>>() function is private, it can still be invoked?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? `x` here is of type `CallInfo`, which has a public `Arg<T>()` method. The `Invoke()` is just another way of calling the `Func` (you could also do `x.Arg<Func<Task<string>>>()()`, but I use `Invoke()` as it looks less confusing to me.